# How do I use if/else statements in shell scripts?

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, terminal

I was wondering how to use an if/else statement to check if a password is right in my unix shell.

Comment: https://www.shellscript.sh/test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the syntax:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is some secure program that uses security.

VALID_PASSWORD="secret" #this is our password.

echo "Please enter the password:"
read PASSWORD

if [ "$PASSWORD" == "$VALID_PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo "You have access!"
else
    echo "ACCESS DENIED!"
fi

bash-3.2$ Please enter the password:
secr
ACCESS DENIED!
bash-3.2$ 

bash-3.2$ Please enter the password:
secret
You have access!"
bash-3.2$
```

[Click here for more on if/else syntax in scripts.](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/ifelse-tutorial.php)

Comment: Syntactically, this is good.  Security-wise, it is less then optimal. The password should be stored in a hashed form, and the data entered should be hashed too, and the two hashes should be compared.  And that's the bare minimum of the changes.

Comment: To get a prompt with read use and because it is a password I'd also recommend the -s option to read, so the password is not visible on the screen while typing it. Plus the -e option helps to prevent funny characters with certain terminals (eg ^H when somebody types a backspace).

    `read -s -e -p "your password: " PASSWORD`

Comment: Yes, the -s, -e, and -p are good for security. Thanks! However, in this question I was just looking for the syntax :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 read -s -e -p "Enter your password: " PASSWORD
 if [ "$PASSWORD" == "password"}; then
      echo "You have access!"
 fi
```